# Identity server 4 federated logout : I want to log out from my app when I logout from the identity provider

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, identityserver4, azure-ad-b2c

I am using identity server 4 with federated login with azure ad . I am currently able to login and logout using identity server. Now I wish to have a feature so that when I logout from azure ad the client automatically logs out from my app ( like in the case of youtube-google, when we logout from youtube we also get logout from google) and vice-versa.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the single sign-out SAML protocol to log out users from multiple applications at once. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-out-saml-protocol?WT.mc_id=ES-MVP-5003833

First you need to configure the logout URL for the application and that you can do it using the App Registration option in Azure AD. In the Properties of the app we have an option for it.

Once this is correctly configured then when the user logout from Access Panel https://myapps.microsoft.com then Azure AD will broadcast the Logout message to your endpoint for SLO.