# Azure AD SSO msal - check if the user is still logged in

Tags: angular, azure, single-sign-on, msal.js

I have 2 WebApps in Angular and these apps are connected via MSAL with SSO.

My problem now is, when I log out in one app I want to be logged out "automatically" in the second app as well.
How can I check in the second app if the user is still logged in. Which event/observer/method can I take for this.

My previous attempts to find something have failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you require it to single logout,  set logout URL. For single sign-out to work correctly, the LogoutURL for the application must be explicitly registered with Azure AD during application registration.

[image]

- But if that’s not working, it may be expected from v2 endpoint, as it looks known issue with v2 endpoint in azure saml sso .
  Make use of v1 logout endpoint  in that case ex: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout` and change it wherever needed in app .
- Please check this [Azure Single Sign Out SAML Protocol - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-out-saml-protocol#logoutrequest)
- Once the logout request is sent to the Microsoft identity platform (the session authority), this request is further sent to ***to all other application / session participants*** except for the one who sent the initial LogoutRequest.
  So  you can check the same in application logs of other applications .

> Azure AD uses the StatusCode element in the Status to indicate the
> success or failure of sign-out.

Once this is correctly configured then, when the user logout from Access Panel at `https://myapps.microsoft.com` then Azure AD will send and cast  the Logout message you’re your endpoint .

see [Identity server 4 federated logout : I want to log out from my app when I logout from the identity provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65474378/identity-server-4-federated-logout-i-want-to-log-out-from-my-app-when-i-logout/65485354#65485354) by @marilee